# Flag clearing with registers reading

Tags: c, flags

When you clear a flag by reading a register and you don't need its content. Is it necessary to affect it to a variable ?
Is this :

```
//clear the flag
MYREGISTER;
```

the same as this :

```
//clear flag
tmp = MYREGISTER;
```

Comment: I suggest that you disassemble your code to see if the instruction is really executed.

Comment: What "flags" are you talking about? Bit-mask flags? `EFLAGS` flags? What is `MYREGISTER;` supposed to exemplify? C does not deal with registers.